# Webform field description to be inline, not popup

Tags: theming, webforms

The description text on a webform text field does not display inline, but pops up in a box when you click into the field.

How do I change this so it is inline like the other fields?

Using Tweme theme

[image]

Comment: I could not replicate this issue using Webform 8.x-5.x. What version of the Webform module are you using? 7 or 8

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7 webform version 7.x-4.17